# Height contraint in storyboard for a custom view with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Starting swift here... How to set a constraint height to a custom view that wrap content or in other words that have a dynamic height ?

In Android we use wrap content or match parent for height. Match parent equivalent for ios is putting top, bottom, left, right constraint to 0 (if I understand well) but what about wrap content ?

Most of the time a custom view height can be dynamic. When I drag a view from the storyboard that extends my custom view, I'a asked for a height constraint... Txs for help !

edited: Why someone put a -1 without giving any reason, is this such a stupid question ?!

Comment: `I'a asked for a height constraint` so your custom view does not have any height? how is it dynamic if it does not have content inside?

Comment: Let's say  I have a textfield inside my custom view, It can have 1, 2 n lines... what if I change font size etc... or inside my custom view I can have a small or large icon... I have no idea about his height. In android we just say height equal wrap content that means it calculates his height according to all the info above.

Comment: if you put there text view or image view storyboard WILL NOT ask you for height, did you try it?

Comment: True but it does for my custom view

Comment: so your custom view is a wrapper or not? if views inside have height, draper is not asked for height

Comment: what do you mean by wrapper ? My view is an input (multiline) field whit a helper text below (or not) and an icon (or not) which make his height totally dynamic. Btw thank for your help ! :)

Comment: @Hiromi - are you using a `UIView` coded for `@IBDesignable`, so you see its contents in Storyboard?

Comment: @DonMag yep I put IBDesignable in front of my class but xcode tells me "designables build fails"...

Comment: @Hiromi - OK, well the first thing you need to do is fix that... otherwise, Storyboard / auto-layout has no idea what's in the view, or how to handle its constraints / sizing / etc. Add the code for your custom view to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is making sure you have configured your custom `@IBDesignable` view correctly.

Here is a simple example, with a `UITextField` and a "helper" `UILabel`.

The text view is set to non-scrolling -- which allows it to auto-size its own height based on the text. It will grow / shrink as you type and add / delete text.

The text view and label are added to a vertical `UIStackView` to make it really, really easy to layout:

```
@IBDesignable
class MyCustomView: UIView {

    let theTextView: UITextView = {
        let v = UITextView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.isScrollEnabled = false
        return v
    }()

    let helperLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.textColor = .white
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        v.text = "Helper Text"
        return v
    }()

    let theStackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fill
        v.spacing = 8
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        // add the stack view as a subview
        addSubview(theStackView)

        // constrain the stack view top / bottom / leading / trailing
        // with 8-pts "padding" on each side
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            theStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            ])

        // add the text view and label to the stack view
        theStackView.addArrangedSubview(theTextView)
        theStackView.addArrangedSubview(helperLabel)

    }

}
```

Now, in a new view controller in Storyboard, add a normal `UIView` and give it a background color (so we can see it). Add Leading and Trailing constraints of `40`, and add a Center Vertically constraint. It should look similar to this:

[image]

and Storyboard will tell you it needs a constraint:

[image]

With the view selected, go to the `Identity Inspector` and change the Class to `MyCustomClass`. If you have **Automatically Refresh Views` turned on, it should change to this:

[image]

It is now centered vertically, and uses its own height (determined by the intrinsic heights of the text view and the label, embedded in the stack view). No more *Needs constraints for: Y position or height* error message, without needing to set any additional constraints.

When you run the app (and type some text into the text view), you'll get this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time of making such a clear response, this is what I call an answer... txs bro ! I solved my promblem with IBDesignable and tested your code and yes it works without height constraint warning.
Let say I I have a cutom button that can be .small or .large, does it mean I have to override intrinsicContentSize to tell the parent about its size ? What if the view change height after being added ? Frame, constriant, intrinsic size etc... are a bit confusing... :) Btw I mark as answerd ! Txs again !

Comment: As long as you maintain proper constraint relationships, you don't have to worry about `intrinsicContentSize`. Keep in mind -- in this example, if you *also* add a height constraint to your view in the storyboard, either the textView or the label will be stretched vertically. So, either design your custom view to manage its own height, or design it to adjust to something else determining its height.